# Copy Tables to another Database with ID Column marked as "generated always" (ORA-32795)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to copy data from a(n Oracle) SQL database to another.

When trying to do so, I get "ORA-32795: cannot insert into a generated always identity column".

I understand that the ID column is markted to be generated and that is fine for usual production.

But I need an exact copy of the data so the IDs need to stay the same. I cannot re-generate them in the new database.

Can I override this config or is there another way to make an exact copy of such tables?

Comment: Restore from backup?

Comment: No, I want to create a copy to try things out.

Comment: Backup the production server and restore on the development server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume that you have the tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY);

CREATE TABLE cloned_table_name (ID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY);
```

With the sample data:

```sql
BEGIN
  FOR i in 1 .. 5 LOOP
    INSERT INTO table_name (id) VALUES (DEFAULT);
  END LOOP;
  DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = 2;
END;
/
```

Then to copy the data from `table_name` to `cloned_table_name` you can change the column in the destination table from `GENERATED ALWAYS` to `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` and then copy and then change the column back to `GENERATED ALWAYS` (with the correct start value):

```sql
ALTER TABLE cloned_table_name
  MODIFY id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY;

INSERT INTO cloned_table_name (id)
SELECT id FROM table_name;

ALTER TABLE cloned_table_name
  MODIFY id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY START WITH 6;
```

Then the tables contain the same data and the next identity value will be correct.

If you want to dynamically generate the `START WITH` value then a simple (naive) method would be to find the maximum value from the table:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_sql VARCHAR2(500);
BEGIN
  SELECT 'ALTER TABLE cloned_table_name
  MODIFY id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY START WITH ' || (MAX(id) + 1)
  INTO   v_sql
  FROM   cloned_table_name;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZqA5Q7Xv)